# New problem linking OpenCV Indigo Cplusplus node

Tags: c++, opencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux Mint 17.1)

I had a problem the other day that turned out to be missing find_package(OpenCV)  so that was resolved.
But I have a new one.  I have a better tracking test that builds and runs fine outside of ROS.  But catkin_make gives this:

catkin_make
Base path: /home/bbick/ros_ws
Source space: /home/bbick/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/bbick/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/bbick/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/bbick/ros_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/bbick/ros_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j6 -l6" in "/home/bbick/ros_ws/build"

[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 11%] Built target talker
[ 22%] Linking CXX executable /home/bbick/ros_ws/devel/lib/inmoovhead/myopencvtest
Built target listener
[ 22%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 22%] [ 22%] [ 22%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 22%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 22%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 22%] [ 22%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[ 33%] Built target pid_gencfg
[ 33%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[ 33%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] [ 33%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 44%] [ 55%] Built target autotune
Built target setpoint_node
[ 66%] Built target plant_sim
[ 77%] Built target controller
[ 88%] Built target sim_time
CMakeFiles/myopencvtest.dir/src/myopencvtest.cpp.o: In function `main': myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to` cv::CommandLineParser::CommandLineParser(int, char const* const*, cv::String const&)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x4aa): undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x54c): undefined reference to` cv::CommandLineParser::printMessage() const'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x8e5): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x91c): undefined reference to` cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x958): undefined reference to `cv::setMouseCallback(cv::String const&, void (*)(int, int, int, int, void*), void*)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x9bb): undefined reference to` cv::createTrackbar(cv::String const&, cv::String const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0xa2d): undefined reference to `cv::createTrackbar(cv::String const&, cv::String const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0xa9f): undefined reference to` cv::createTrackbar(cv::String const&, cv::String const&, int*, int, void (*)(int, void*), void*)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0xff0): undefined reference to `cv::normalize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, double, double, int, int, cv::_InputArray const&)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x12b4): undefined reference to` cv::rectangle(cv::*InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point*, cv::Point_, cv::Scalar_ const&, int, int, int)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x176c): undefined reference to `cv::ellipse(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::RotatedRect const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x18aa): undefined reference to` cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x190e): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x1a09): undefined reference to` cv::destroyWindow(cv::String const&)'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x1a42): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x1b39): undefined reference to` cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()'
myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x1b78): undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()' myopencvtest.cpp:(.text+0x218b): undefined reference to` cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()'
CMakeFiles/myopencvtest.dir/src/myopencvtest.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)': myopencvtest.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x4f): undefined reference to` cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/myopencvtest.dir/src/myopencvtest.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()': myopencvtest.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to` cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/myopencvtest.dir/src/myopencvtest.cpp.o: In function `int cv::CommandLineParser::get<int>(int, bool) const': myopencvtest.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv17CommandLineParser3getIiEET_ib[_ZNK2cv17CommandLineParser3getIiEET_ib]+0x36): undefined reference to` cv::CommandLineParser::getByIndex(int, bool, int, void*) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/bbick/ros_ws/devel/lib/inmoovhead/myopencvtest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [inmoovhead/CMakeFiles/myopencvtest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j6 -l6" failed
==== End of catkin_make output

So it appears to NOT find the C++ libraries that are required for this to link.
And here's my CMakeLists.txt: (With most commented out stuff removed for brevity)

make_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(inmoovhead)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
message_generation
)

################################################

### Declare ROS messages, services and actions

################################################

### Generate messages in the 'msg' folder

add_message_files(
FILES
Num.msg
)

################################################

### Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters

################################################

###################################

### catkin specific configuration

###################################

### The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package

### Declare things to be passed to dependent projects

### INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files

### LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need

### CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need

### DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need

catkin_package(

## INCLUDE_DIRS include

## LIBRARIES inmoovhead

## CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs

## DEPENDS system_lib

CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)

###########

### Build

###########

### Specify additional locations of header files

### Your package locations should be listed before other locations

## include_directories(include)

include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

### Declare a C++ library

## add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/inmoovhead.cpp

## )

### Add cmake target dependencies of the executable

### same as for the library above

## add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

### Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against

## target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

## )

### Add folders to be run by python nosetests

## catkin_add_nosetests(test)

find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(myopencvtest src/myopencvtest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myopencvtest ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

## add_dependencies(myopencvtest myopencvtest_generate_messages_cpp)

===== End of CMakeLIsts.txt

What am I missing to get the required libraries to be found?
My opencv libs are in /usr/local/lib

Thanks,
Burt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259991/new-problem-linking-opencv-indigo-cplusplus---node/) by [burtbick](https://answers.ros.org/users/30032/burtbick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2017-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2017-04-23**:
Please add your CMakeList.txt so people can help you.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
I ran a cut-down version of your CMakeLists.txt on the first OpenCV sample (contours2.cpp), and it compiled fine. Please post your source files and the complete output of catkin_make so we can see what values it is finding when it searches for OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had pasted in the CMakeLIsts.txt file contents, just removed most of the commented lines to try and keep it brief, but it looks like the editor here mucked it up, or there is some different way to enter the code that cleans it up.

So..

Here's a link to the CMakeLists.txt file (renamed to BBCMakeLists.txt, only for this download)

[My CMakeLists.txt](https://files.secureserver.net/0sm0hul129xeUu)

And to the OpenCV sample that I've enhanced to track my robot head.  Note that this sample DOES not have the ROS code in but it has the same linking errors as my full application.  Note also that I built the version of the app that integrates with ROS externally and it runs fine with ROS, and I have my head tracking well.  But it won't link when built with the ROS build system using catkin_make.  Other OpenCV tests I've done HAVE built and linked OK with catkin_make.

[My Sample C++ File](https://files.secureserver.net/0s7vUbnP1ITJKL)

Here's the only output I get from catkin_make, note I did a catkin_make clean first and then catkin_make

Since pasting the catkin_make output also seems to jumble up, here's a link to the output that I get:

[catkin_make output](https://files.secureserver.net/0s0IK9BE5uegct)

You should be able to download the files with no problems, but let me know if there is a problem.

Thanks,
Burt

---

Originally posted by [burtbick](https://answers.ros.org/users/30032/burtbick/) with karma: 201 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
You need to delete the `build/` and `devel/` directories before running `catkin_make`, otherwise the configure step is skipped. Delete those two directories, then run `VERBOSE=1 catkin_make` and post the output.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
Your code compiled fine for me, by the way.

**Comment by [burtbick](https://answers.ros.org/users/30032/burtbick/) on 2017-04-25**:
Thanks Geoff,

I deleted build and devel and when I was building to gather the catkin_make output for you it built cleanly!!! The only thing I had done differently was deleting build and devel  directory trees.  So there must have been something in the old trees that was causing the problem.